# react testing, button not clicking from userevent

Tags: react-testing-library

im trying to do a write a test where i can click a button in a react component but its not working and i don't know why. as far as i can tell this should be working. im expecting the callback to be called once.

```
it("should work", () => {
  var mockCallback = jest.fn();
  render(<button onClick={mockCallback}>hello world</button>);
  act(() => {
    let test = screen.getByRole("button");
    console.log(test);
    userEvent.click(test);
  });
  expect(mockCallback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

[here is a link to a codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-smoke-f0hfjx?file=/src/App.test.js)

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userEvent.click` returns a `Promise<void>` as you can see [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/convenience#click). So, to your test work you need to make your test `async` and `await` the click event:

```js
it("should work", async () => {
    var mockCallback = jest.fn();

    render(<button onClick={mockCallback}>hello world</button>);

    const button = screen.getByRole("button");

    screen.debug();

    await userEvent.click(button);

    expect(mockCallback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

* Also, you don´t need the `act` in this case. Check more about it [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/preact-testing-library/api/#act).